# SETroubleShoot "unrecognized service" error

Tags: linux, selinux

I installed the package but I'm getting an "unrecognized service" error:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo yum install setroubleshoot
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package setroubleshoot.x86_64 0:2.2.94-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                       Arch                                                  Version                                                        Repository                                         Size
============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 setroubleshoot                                                x86_64                                                2.2.94-1.el6                                                   sl                                                138 k

Transaction Summary
============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 138 k
Installed size: 294 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
setroubleshoot-2.2.94-1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                               | 138 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : setroubleshoot-2.2.94-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                       1/1 

Installed:
  setroubleshoot.x86_64 0:2.2.94-1.el6                                                                                                                                                                                                      

Complete!
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ rpm -q setroubleshoot
setroubleshoot-2.2.94-1.el6.x86_64
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo service setroubleshoot 
setroubleshoot: unrecognized service
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo service setroubleshoot-server 
setroubleshoot-server: unrecognized service
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ ls /etc/init.d/s*
/etc/init.d/sandbox  /etc/init.d/saslauthd  /etc/init.d/single  /etc/init.d/smartd  /etc/init.d/smb  /etc/init.d/snmpd  /etc/init.d/snmptrapd  /etc/init.d/spice-vdagentd  /etc/init.d/sshd  /etc/init.d/sssd  /etc/init.d/sysstat
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running 'rpm -qf /etc/init.d/setroubleshoot --qf="%{NAME}\n";' yields "setroubleshoot-server". This package contains the /etc/init.d/setroubleshoot SysV init script to start the service.

Comment: I'm not sure what your command suppose to do, can you just explain it?

Comment: Sorry, way late response. What I meant is that you also need to install the "setroubleshoot-server" package which contains the /usr/sbin/setroubleshootd binary and the /etc/rc.d/init.d/setroubleshoot script to start the service with.

Comment: setroubleshoot-server _IS_ installed same thing though